# Is "cat"ing a file an useless step when working with bash script?

Tags: bash, file

Would it be useless to cat a file when reading it in bash script?

Should I "cat" the file and then send the content to the "while", like:

```
myFileContent="$(cat "$myfile")"
while IFS='' read -r lineRead || [[ -n "$lineRead " ]]; do
    <some important code here>
done <<< "$myFileContent"
```

or should I just send the file straight to the while, like:

```
while IFS='' read -r lineRead || [[ -n "$lineRead " ]]; do
    <some important code here>
done < "$myfile"
```

Comment: I can't think of a good reason why you would want to complicate things with a superfluous `cat`. Is there any reason why you feel compelled to read your file into a variable before iterating through the contents?

Comment: Actually, I'm just worried that since this code will be used in many Unix and Linux distributions, I wanted it as portable as possible.

Comment: So why don't you put your answer that way ? If you are concerned that the second solution is not compatible with every bash version ask or check this.

Comment: Using `cat` loads the entire file into memory. Using the redirection does not.

Comment: I think there are a few Bash versions that do not support `<<<` so your solution here for wide compatibility is suspect.

Comment: @dawg , thanks for that input! That disqualify the use of <<< for me. I saw that as an example to avoid another problem... I didn't know I was about to fall into another one.

Comment: The version with `$(cat...)` will also lose any trailing blank lines in the input, which may or may not matter.

Comment: @dawg `bash` has supported `<<<` since 2.0.5b, so that isn't going to be a big issue.

Comment: @chepner this discussion is awesome! You guys saved me hours of research! I would like to thank everyone!

Comment: @chepner: Showing my age I suppose ;-/ I do remember when here strings were NEW! Thanks for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
while IFS='' read -r lineRead || [[ -n "$lineRead " ]]; do
    <some important code here>
done < "$myfile"
```

I see two advantages
1. This saves you from using additional line of code.
2. If the file is really huge, why do you want to load it into memory ?

Answer (score 2):

Why not using a simple input redirection :

```
while IFS='' read -r lineRead || [[ -n "$lineRead " ]]; do
    <some important code here>
done < "$myfile"
```

You avoid `$(cat "$myfile")` subprocess.

Comment: Copy and paste error... I normally use only one "<".
The thing is, I want this code as portable as possible.
I don't know if while will behave like that everywhere.

Comment: @timgeb The question has been updated while i was typing. Simple input redirection was not an alternative at this moment. Updated my answer on benefits.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the size of the files you are processing.

If they are tiny a few kilobytes, it really does not matter these days. Though like my colleges I would prefer the second option just because of the waste in processing/storage. (cat is an extra process started and then you have to store the content of the file in memory)

If they are gigabytes sized files then the first approach is bad, and at that point the while read loop would not be a good choice either, way too slow. At that point, I would process using stream processing tools like sed or awk to implement the entire logic.

Comment: The cat-less approach strikes me as the better one in any scenario. If the files come from user input or from *somewhere*, or somebody is catting from standard input, you won't know if they could get too large. it just makes less unnecessary assumptions.

Comment: The `|| [[ -n $line ]]` idiom is to handle unterminated final lines of content. A file without a trailing newline will fail to have the final line processed without this, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of any case where it is an advantage to read your file into memory first, but I can imagine that there are reasons to do so.

However, you do not have to use `cat` to read the file into memory:

```
myFileContent=$(<"$myfile")
```

As you can see, command substitution works with only the redirection as well.